# Informatica Parameter String

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a question:

I have a parameter file with:

```
$$DEPARTMENTS_1 = 'ITS','FINAN','RHM','OP'
$$DEPARTMENTS_2 = 'TECH','BI','FIELD','MECH'
```

I use the parameter in the source qualifier and it work fine

```
SELECT NAME,PAY,EMPLOYEE_DEPART
FROM HR_DB
WHERE EMPLOYEE_DEPART IN ($$DEPARTMENTS_1,$$DEPARTMENTS_2)
```

But, In need to use in mapping to use in expression:

```
DECODE(TRUE,
IN(EMPLOYEE_DEPART,$$DEPARTMENTS_1),'DEPARTMENT-1',
IN(EMPLOYEE_DEPART,$$DEPARTMENTS_2),'DEPARTMENT-2','NO-DEPARTMENT')
```

Gave me NO-DEPARTMENT to all my records.

How I can pass the string list to use in the DECODE.

Comment: Have you tried setting IsExprVar=true and making sure length of all parameters are fine. Also run in verbose mode and see how its coming in sess log.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use mapping parameter and assign the parameter values. Post that use the parameter in the decode.

Go through these documents,

https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-2/designer-guide/mapping-parameters-and-variables/mapping-parameters-and-variables-overview.html

https://www.guru99.com/mappings-informatica.html